# Can't dismiss progressDialog from activity callback

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know there are a million similar questions here, but none of the solutions presented there quite addressed the issue I'm having. I have an `AsyncTask` that loads data from a database. An indeterminate `ProgressDialog` is displayed while the data is loading (even though in production code it never takes a visibly apparent time to load the database, but just in case someone builds a huge one).

I used to call and dismiss the `ProgressDialog` directly from the `AsyncTask`, and it worked fine. The problem is, I'm trying to enforce better separation of concerns and I decided that displaying things to the screen does not fall in the `AsyncTask`'s domain, and really belongs to the activity. So I implemented a callback interface to the activity, and in the activity I have:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Loading. . .",true,true);
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        Logger.d("Dismissing progress dialog");
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Logcat shows that I'm reaching that logger line, but the `ProgressDialog` never dismisses. Is there some reason why I can't do this in a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what's happening here is that multiple `ProgressDialog`'s are being instantiated.

Therefore, while `dismiss()` is successfully called, it's not called on the `ProgressDialog` currently visible on your screen, and you've lost your reference to this visible one since you've overwritten `progressDialog` with a new object instance.

Try putting `Logger.d("New ProgressDialog");` where you are creating a new instance of the `ProgressDialog`, and you will most likely see this scenario confirmed.

You could probably fix this by using an `Array`/`List` to keep track of all  of your `ProgressDialog`s and dismiss the appropriate one when it's corresponding `AsyncTask` completes, but personally I think this is far more convoluted then your original approach of having each `AsyncTask` handle their own `ProgressDialog`'s lifecycle.

Comment: You were right. I had moved the creation of the `AsyncTask` and never deleted the original, so it was being created twice.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
if(progressDialog == null) {
    // initialize your progress dialog object 
}
if (progressDialog.isShowing() && progress != null) {
    progress.dismiss();
}
```